# HTML page displaying PHP code instead of running it

Tags: php, html, mysql

In my HTML web page I want to make my dropdown menu pull options from a MySQL database, so I embedded PHP inside. However, when you select the drop down it is saying `'.$id.'` literally rather than a name that it should.

```
<label>Test Dropdown</label>
<select class="form-control" name="client">
    <option value="pick">CHOOSE</option>
    <?php
        $dbhost = '#########';
        $dbuser = '#########';
        $dbpass = '$$$$$$$$$$$$$$';
        $dbdata = '############';
        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM client";
        mysql_select_db('######');
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn);

        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $id = $row['fname'];
                echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$id.'</option>';
            }
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions, they are deprecated

Comment: so what should i use instead? what format?

Comment: Use MySQLI or PDO, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/2595450)

Comment: that still doesn't explain why it isn't echoing out the option form in full and why the html displays the literal php code

Comment: Yes I know, but I'm not helping with an unsecure code, and I don't think anyone will, more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/2595450)

Comment: Are you running a `.html` page or `.php` one ? Double check the extension .

Comment: its .html. even if the php is embeded inside html does it have to be .php?

Comment: you must change the page to .php for it to read the php...

Comment: @JordanFarris Sure.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that output i.e .$id. that's because you have put it into inverted comma, so it is taking it as an string rather than variable so try this:

```
 echo '<option value="'.$id.'">.$id.</option>';
```

instead of

```
echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$id.'</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If your website can serve actual .php files, but the php code doesn't execute in your .html or .htm , chances are you need to add php support at the webserver level.

- Most hosting plans are usually on a LAMP stack and support PHP. If you have such a hosting plan, this can be done using an .htaccess file or through the CPanel/Plesk interface.  Refer to [this blog post](https://www.rssinclude.com/blog/36_how_to_run_php_scripts_in_html_or_htm_files) that explains how to test if php works on your server and get it working within .html or .htm files.
- However, if you have a custom webserver or an IIS server, you may need to install and configure PHP support before you can even enable it for html files.)